# CNN, GAN, How can the Generator know, what class it should draw?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, embedding

I have a GAN network. the generator is drawing mnist digits. It works great. But I cant understand how it knows, which digit it should draw.
Here is the Generator:

```
def build_generator(latent_size):
    # we will map a pair of (z, L), where z is a latent vector and L is a
    # label drawn from P_c, to image space (..., 1, 28, 28)
    cnn = Sequential()

    cnn.add(Dense(1024, input_dim=latent_size, activation='relu'))
    cnn.add(Dense(128 * 7 * 7, activation='relu'))
    cnn.add(Reshape((128, 7, 7)))

    # upsample to (..., 14, 14)
    cnn.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
    cnn.add(Conv2D(256, 5, padding='same',
                   activation='relu',
                   kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))

    # upsample to (..., 28, 28)
    cnn.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
    cnn.add(Conv2D(128, 5, padding='same',
                   activation='relu',
                   kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))

    # take a channel axis reduction
    cnn.add(Conv2D(1, 2, padding='same',
                   activation='tanh',
                   kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))

    # this is the z space commonly refered to in GAN papers
    latent = Input(shape=(latent_size, ))

    # this will be our label
    image_class = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')

    cls = Flatten()(Embedding(num_classes, latent_size,
                              embeddings_initializer='glorot_normal')(image_class))

    # hadamard product between z-space and a class conditional embedding
    h = layers.multiply([latent, cls])

    fake_image = cnn(h)

    return Model([latent, image_class], fake_image)
```

The Input is a latent-array

```
noise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (batch_size, latent_size))
```

and the labels are just generated randomly.

So my question is. After the network is embedding the labels. They should look like this

[image: Embedding Labels]

So, now. If I give the network more latent-arrays and labels. He is multiplying the latent-arrays(the noise) with the embedding(of the labels):
So what I expect is:

[image: What I expect]

So the network knows, what new array represents what number.

but the output of np.multiply(noise,embedded_label) is this:

[image: What is Reality]

So how can the network know, what digit it should draw?

### EDIT:

So here is the whole code. And it works. But why?
The latent_size in the code is 100. The latent_size in my pictures is 2, because I wanted to visualize them. But i think it doesn't change a thing, if I multiply the noise in the 2 dimensional space or the 100 dimensional space. At the end the new points with label "1" are not close to the other points with label "1". Same for the other digits("0","1","2","3",...)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Train an Auxiliary Classifier Generative Adversarial Network (ACGAN) on the
MNIST dataset. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.09585 for more details.

You should start to see reasonable images after ~5 epochs, and good images
by ~15 epochs. You should use a GPU, as the convolution-heavy operations are
very slow on the CPU. Prefer the TensorFlow backend if you plan on iterating,
as the compilation time can be a blocker using Theano.

Timings:

Hardware           | Backend | Time / Epoch
-------------------------------------------
 CPU               | TF      | 3 hrs
 Titan X (maxwell) | TF      | 4 min
 Titan X (maxwell) | TH      | 7 min

Consult https://github.com/lukedeo/keras-acgan for more information and
example output
"""
from __future__ import print_function

from collections import defaultdict
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:
    import pickle
from PIL import Image

from six.moves import range

import keras.backend as K
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras import layers
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Reshape, Flatten, Embedding, Dropout
from keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
from keras.layers.convolutional import UpSampling2D, Conv2D
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils.generic_utils import Progbar
import numpy as np
import time, os
np.random.seed(1337)

K.set_image_data_format('channels_first')

num_classes = 10


def build_generator(latent_size):
    # we will map a pair of (z, L), where z is a latent vector and L is a
    # label drawn from P_c, to image space (..., 1, 28, 28)
    cnn = Sequential()

    cnn.add(Dense(1024, input_dim=latent_size, activation='relu'))
    cnn.add(Dense(128 * 7 * 7, activation='relu'))
    cnn.add(Reshape((128, 7, 7)))

    # upsample to (..., 14, 14)
    cnn.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
    cnn.add(Conv2D(256, 5, padding='same',
                   activation='relu',
                   kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))

    # upsample to (..., 28, 28)
    cnn.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2, 2)))
    cnn.add(Conv2D(128, 5, padding='same',
                   activation='relu',
                   kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))

    # take a channel axis reduction
    cnn.add(Conv2D(1, 2, padding='same',
                   activation='tanh',
                   kernel_initializer='glorot_normal'))

    # this is the z space commonly refered to in GAN papers
    latent = Input(shape=(latent_size, ))

    # this will be our label
    image_class = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')

    cls = Flatten()(Embedding(num_classes, latent_size,
                              embeddings_initializer='glorot_normal')(image_class))

    # hadamard product between z-space and a class conditional embedding
    h = layers.multiply([latent, cls])

    fake_image = cnn(h)

    return Model([latent, image_class], fake_image)


def build_discriminator():
    # build a relatively standard conv net, with LeakyReLUs as suggested in
    # the reference paper
    cnn = Sequential()

    cnn.add(Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', strides=2,
                   input_shape=(1, 28, 28)))
    cnn.add(LeakyReLU())
    cnn.add(Dropout(0.3))

    cnn.add(Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', strides=1))
    cnn.add(LeakyReLU())
    cnn.add(Dropout(0.3))

    cnn.add(Conv2D(128, 3, padding='same', strides=2))
    cnn.add(LeakyReLU())
    cnn.add(Dropout(0.3))

    cnn.add(Conv2D(256, 3, padding='same', strides=1))
    cnn.add(LeakyReLU())
    cnn.add(Dropout(0.3))

    cnn.add(Flatten())

    image = Input(shape=(1, 28, 28))

    features = cnn(image)

    # first output (name=generation) is whether or not the discriminator
    # thinks the image that is being shown is fake, and the second output
    # (name=auxiliary) is the class that the discriminator thinks the image
    # belongs to.
    fake = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='generation')(features) # fake oder nicht fake
    aux = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='auxiliary')(features) #welche klasse ist es

    return Model(image, [fake, aux])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time_string = time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S", time.gmtime())
    os.mkdir('history/' + start_time_string)
    os.mkdir('images/' + start_time_string)
    os.mkdir('acgan/' + start_time_string)
    # batch and latent size taken from the paper
    epochs = 50
    batch_size = 100
    latent_size = 100

    # Adam parameters suggested in https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06434
    adam_lr = 0.00005
    adam_beta_1 = 0.5

    # build the discriminator
    discriminator = build_discriminator()
    discriminator.compile(
        optimizer=Adam(lr=adam_lr, beta_1=adam_beta_1),
        loss=['binary_crossentropy', 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy']
    )

    # build the generator
    generator = build_generator(latent_size)
    generator.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=adam_lr, beta_1=adam_beta_1),
                      loss='binary_crossentropy')

    latent = Input(shape=(latent_size, ))
    image_class = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32')

    # get a fake image
    fake = generator([latent, image_class])

    # we only want to be able to train generation for the combined model
    discriminator.trainable = False
    fake, aux = discriminator(fake)
    combined = Model([latent, image_class], [fake, aux])

    combined.compile(
        optimizer=Adam(lr=adam_lr, beta_1=adam_beta_1),
        loss=['binary_crossentropy', 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy']
    )

    # get our mnist data, and force it to be of shape (..., 1, 28, 28) with
    # range [-1, 1]
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train = (x_train.astype(np.float32) - 127.5) / 127.5
    x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, axis=1)

    x_test = (x_test.astype(np.float32) - 127.5) / 127.5
    x_test = np.expand_dims(x_test, axis=1)

    num_train, num_test = x_train.shape[0], x_test.shape[0]

    train_history = defaultdict(list)
    test_history = defaultdict(list)

    for epoch in range(1, epochs + 1):
        print('Epoch {}/{}'.format(epoch, epochs))

        num_batches = int(x_train.shape[0] / batch_size)
        progress_bar = Progbar(target=num_batches)

        epoch_gen_loss = []
        epoch_disc_loss = []

        for index in range(num_batches):
            # generate a new batch of noise
            noise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (batch_size, latent_size))

            # get a batch of real images
            image_batch = x_train[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]
            label_batch = y_train[index * batch_size:(index + 1) * batch_size]

            # sample some labels from p_c
            sampled_labels = np.random.randint(0, num_classes, batch_size)

            # generate a batch of fake images, using the generated labels as a
            # conditioner. We reshape the sampled labels to be
            # (batch_size, 1) so that we can feed them into the embedding
            # layer as a length one sequence
            generated_images = generator.predict(
                [noise, sampled_labels.reshape((-1, 1))], verbose=0)

            x = np.concatenate((image_batch, generated_images))
            y = np.array([1] * batch_size + [0] * batch_size)
            aux_y = np.concatenate((label_batch, sampled_labels), axis=0)

            # see if the discriminator can figure itself out...
            epoch_disc_loss.append(discriminator.train_on_batch(x, [y, aux_y]))

            # make new noise. we generate 2 * batch size here such that we have
            # the generator optimize over an identical number of images as the
            # discriminator
            noise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (2 * batch_size, latent_size))
            sampled_labels = np.random.randint(0, num_classes, 2 * batch_size)

            # we want to train the generator to trick the discriminator
            # For the generator, we want all the {fake, not-fake} labels to say
            # not-fake
            trick = np.ones(2 * batch_size)

            epoch_gen_loss.append(combined.train_on_batch(
                [noise, sampled_labels.reshape((-1, 1))],
                [trick, sampled_labels]))

            progress_bar.update(index + 1)

        print('Testing for epoch {}:'.format(epoch))

        # evaluate the testing loss here

        # generate a new batch of noise
        noise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (num_test, latent_size))

        # sample some labels from p_c and generate images from them
        sampled_labels = np.random.randint(0, num_classes, num_test)
        generated_images = generator.predict(
            [noise, sampled_labels.reshape((-1, 1))], verbose=False)

        x = np.concatenate((x_test, generated_images))
        y = np.array([1] * num_test + [0] * num_test)
        aux_y = np.concatenate((y_test, sampled_labels), axis=0)

        # see if the discriminator can figure itself out...
        discriminator_test_loss = discriminator.evaluate(
            x, [y, aux_y], verbose=False)

        discriminator_train_loss = np.mean(np.array(epoch_disc_loss), axis=0)

        # make new noise
        noise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (2 * num_test, latent_size))
        sampled_labels = np.random.randint(0, num_classes, 2 * num_test)

        trick = np.ones(2 * num_test)

        generator_test_loss = combined.evaluate(
            [noise, sampled_labels.reshape((-1, 1))],
            [trick, sampled_labels], verbose=False)

        generator_train_loss = np.mean(np.array(epoch_gen_loss), axis=0)

        # generate an epoch report on performance
        train_history['generator'].append(generator_train_loss)
        train_history['discriminator'].append(discriminator_train_loss)

        test_history['generator'].append(generator_test_loss)
        test_history['discriminator'].append(discriminator_test_loss)

        print('{0:<22s} | {1:4s} | {2:15s} | {3:5s}'.format(
            'component', *discriminator.metrics_names))
        print('-' * 65)

        ROW_FMT = '{0:<22s} | {1:<4.2f} | {2:<15.2f} | {3:<5.2f}'
        print(ROW_FMT.format('generator (train)',
                             *train_history['generator'][-1]))
        print(ROW_FMT.format('generator (test)',
                             *test_history['generator'][-1]))
        print(ROW_FMT.format('discriminator (train)',
                             *train_history['discriminator'][-1]))
        print(ROW_FMT.format('discriminator (test)',
                             *test_history['discriminator'][-1]))

        # save weights every epoch
        generator.save_weights(
            'acgan/'+ start_time_string +'/params_generator_epoch_{0:03d}.hdf5'.format(epoch), True)
        discriminator.save_weights(
            'acgan/'+ start_time_string +'/params_discriminator_epoch_{0:03d}.hdf5'.format(epoch), True)

        # generate some digits to display
        noise = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (100, latent_size))

        sampled_labels = np.array([
            [i] * num_classes for i in range(num_classes)
        ]).reshape(-1, 1)

        # get a batch to display
        generated_images = generator.predict(
            [noise, sampled_labels], verbose=0)

        # arrange them into a grid
        img = (np.concatenate([r.reshape(-1, 28)
                               for r in np.split(generated_images, num_classes)
                               ], axis=-1) * 127.5 + 127.5).astype(np.uint8)

        Image.fromarray(img).save(
            'images/'+ start_time_string +'/plot_epoch_{0:03d}_generated.png'.format(epoch))

    pickle.dump({'train': train_history, 'test': test_history},
                open('history/'+ start_time_string +'/acgan-history.pkl', 'wb'))
```

Comment: What is the value of "latent_size"?

Comment: So, in the code for the digit drawing with the GAN. It is 100. But in the pictures it is 2, because I want to visualize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your noise is too big, and has negative values.

You should not multiply the noise, but sum it (and make it a lot smaller). 
By multiplying +1 and -1, you can completely change the input. That's the reason for having that completely scattered image in [reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVZAY.png).

If even with that weird scattered input the model is still able to recognize the number you meant, then it's probably using certain dimensions of the latent vector more than its actual values.

If you look closely to the scattered graph, it has some interesting patterns such as:

- 0 - a vertical line. It used only a certain dimension to be zero.
- 4 - another vertical line.
- 7 - a horizontal line.
- 3 - seems to be a diagonal, not sure.

[image: see picture]

If we can see a pattern (even in a 2D graph hiding actual 100 dimensions), the model can also see a pattern. This pattern might be extremely evident if we could see all the 100 dimensions.

So, your embedding is probably creating a compensation for the wild random factors, maybe by eliminating the random factors with zeros in certain groups of dimensions. That makes the straight lines following certain axes. And certain combinations zero dimensions versus varying dimensions may identify a label.

Example:

- For the label 0, your embedding may be creating [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...]
- For the label 1, it may be creating [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1....]
- For the label 2, it may be creating [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1...]

Then the random factor will never change those zeros, and the model can identify a number by checking those groups of four zeros in the examples.

Of course, this is just one supposition... there might be many other possible ways for the model to work around the random factors... but if one exists, it's enough to show that it's ok for the model to find it.

Comment: I don't understand that. So my embedding creates for label "0" always the same array, array_0. After it creates the array_0 i multiply the noise. So how can the embedding 'create a compensation for the wild random factors'? Because after I multiply the noise (noise*array_0=array_0_with_noise) every array_0_with_noise is totally different and not close to array_0 anymore. BTW: I edited my post with the complete code. Maybe that helps.

Comment: See the picture added in the answer. If we can see a pattern, the model can also see a pattern. Instead of searching for certain specific values, your model is searching for certain specific dimensions instead.

Comment: For instance, one possibility is that the embedding decided that for say the label 8, the first 10 elements in the latent dimension (100) will always be zero. Then it's easy to identify an eight by checking if the first ten elements are zero (zeros eliminate the random factor multiplied). The other 90 elements can be whatever they like and the chance of many of them being zero is small.

Comment: So, if i create my own embedding arrays. and they look like this: `array_0=[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, random_uniform(90, minval=-1.0,maxval=1.0], array_1=[0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, random_uniform(90, minval=-1.0,maxval=1.0], array_3=[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, random_uniform(90, minval=-1.0,maxval=1.0]`, same for array_3 and so on. then The code should work the same, right? But its not, it just gives me the same images

Comment: Or I create an array with 90 zeros and 10 ones, that should work? I tried, but every created image that is a 0 looks exact the same. with the other digits its the same. but when I use the Keras embedding it works. I cant understand that. because my number are embedded too and I multiply the same noise.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe my hypothesis is not the right one... but you might try 10 zeros and 90 ones too....